# C Newbie Syntax Error

Tags: c

I am trying to write code that opens an external file, and prints out the lines in that file, but keep getting

Line 7: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit'

Line 15: error: expected expression before '%' token
Line 15: error: stray '\' in program

When trying to compile this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: strgen <file>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *infile = argv[1];
    FILE *fp = fopen(infile, "r");
    assert(fp != NULL);
    char buffer[50];
    while( fgets( buffer, 50, fp) != NULL){
        printf("%d\n",buffer);
        printf(%s\n, buffer);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Missing quotation marks around `%s\n`

Comment: Interesting place to hide that `printf()`. Thanks to Brian for fixing the formatting.

Comment: You need to add `#include <stdlib.h>` for the first error.

Comment: You do `return(0)`, why not just do `return (1)` for the error message, and skip the `exit` entirely?

Comment: There must be a canonical question for leaving out quotes for strings. Where is it?

Answer (score 5):

Two problems:

1. You need to `#include <stdlib.h>` to get the declaration of `exit()`
2. You need quotes around the `%s\n` in the second `printf()` statement

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you formatted your code correctly. There's a stray `printf` statement in there without any quotes around the `%s\n`, hence the error.

Comment: For the second error? (Line 15)

Answer (score 0):

you need to include header file

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: For the first error? (Line 7)